# How to cancel the Connect to your target Linux system in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When I download visual studio  for the first time and when I write any code, the program asks me to Connect to your target Linux system in Visual Studio And I really don't need it How can I cancel it?

I tried to search for the topic, but the results were about canceling the contact information for a specific device, not canceling the entire feature.

| Severity | Code | Description | Project | File | Line | Suppression State | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error |  | There are no remote machines configured for remote builds. Please configure a machine using Tools | Options | Cross Platform | Connection Manager | ConsoleApplication2 | C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets | 160 |  |  |

Comment: can you please send an image? there's a lot of cases for that explanation, i need you to be more spesific

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do not add any tags that do not relate to the question. I removed the Java, Python, JS, and HTML tags.